# ngModelChange value undefined when passed to function

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ngmodel, mat-autocomplete

I am using Angular autocomplete which I have connected to an API. Search results should not be returned until after typing has started. After typing a few letters in the box this error comes up in the console.

***ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'xxxx'. Current value: 'undefined'..***

I have tried using change detection but that hasn't helped.

The main issue seems to be with the collectFieldValue function because, without it, when I console log the value, the value never becomes undefined.

Search.component.html

```
    <input type="text" class="searchItem" placeholder="Begin your’"
    aria-label="Begin your search" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" (ngModelChange)="inputCheck($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="searchInput" (focusout)="onFocusOut()" (focus)="onFocus()"
    (keydown)="onKeyDown()" >
```

Search.component.ts

```
@Input() setSelectedLocation!: Function;

     inputCheck(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined && value !== "" && value !== null) 
        {
          this.collectFieldValue(value, this.sharedService.sharedVal && this.sharedService.sharedVal !== "" ? this.sharedService.sharedVal : undefined)
        }
      }
```

Main.component.html

```
<app-search-box
    [collectFieldValue]="triggerLocationSearch"
    [setSelectedLocation]="setSelectedLocation">
</app-search-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` usually happens when something in template changes before the entire template is rendered the first time. E.g some function in template changes template itself.

Wrap the suspected method in `setTimeout` to trigger this in next cycle. If that removes the error then you've found out the culprit.

Afterwards figure out why template change happens before it's rendered. Right not I can't spot the problem.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
 this.collectFieldValue(value, this.sharedService.sharedVal && this.sharedService.sharedVal !== "" ? this.sharedService.sharedVal : undefined)
})
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: It was just a guess, you need to find the problematic area yourself.Iindeed it may not be the one I showed the example with.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after modifying a Map object that was being iterated over using

```
*ngFor="let entry of myMap.entries()"
```

The fix that worked for me was adding ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush to my component declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})..
```